# Primes in N (estimation)

Tags: primes

I would like to know if there is any way (like a formula) to estimate how many prime numbers are there in an interval [0,N]. i.e. "How many prime numbers there are up to 120?"
I don't want to count and I dont want to know which numbers are these. I just need a estimation of how many are them.

Thank you.

Comment: Read all about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem.

Comment: This is probably a better question for [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Indeed https://primes.utm.edu/howmany.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f(x) = number of primes less than x
f(x) can be approximated by x/logx.
```

There are better but more complicated approximations, but a function for calculating this exactly is not known yet.

Comment: you probably meant a *formula* for calculating this isn't known yet.